# Assign a PHP variable within a javascipt script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a legacy application built in jquery and PHP. I'm not sure how to assign the variable correctly. The PHP part is blank when a view source.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOd('age') >= 0){
  <?php
      $width = '750px'
  ?>
} else {
    $width = '500px'
}
```

The width variable is then assigned using jquery

```
$('#main-dev').attr('style', max-width:<?php echo $width;?>");
```

This isn't apply the correct width.

Any ideas why the php variable isn't taking?

The JS above appears in the source like

```
if(window.location.href.indexOd('age') >= 0){
} else {
}
```

I've never used PHP before, just trying to work on this legacy site?

Comment: `indexOd` should be `indexOf`

Comment: You're mixing up [client and server side programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming).

Comment: The whole question makes little sense. Of course your JS if/else blocks are empty - because you only assigned a value to a PHP variable in between those lines, but you did not create any output. And why involve PHP in the first place? You want to _set_ a value on the client side, based on another value you _read_ on the client side.

Comment: You likely want to do something like this, `$('#main-dev').style('max-width', window.location.href.indexOf('age') >= 0 ? '750px' : '500px');`

Answer (score 0):

Create a var "width" in JS global scope and change value. Attention, the correct is "indexOf".

```
var width = '500px';
if(window.location.href.indexOf('age') >= 0){
    width = '750px';
}
```

So, use the "width" var.

```
$('#main-dev').attr('style', 'max-width:' + width);
```